# java + which of these will not cause the thread to stop : wait,notify,sleep,One more option

Tags: java, multithreading

I have been asked this question, in a multiple choice question(only 1 is correct) test, but I am not sure what can be the answer to this

```
which of these will not cause the thread to stop ?  
wait,notify,sleep,One more option provided(i dont remember)
```

I understand these pretty much, but not sure what is the answer of this question, and looking for the same

Answer (score 2):

`wait` --> The thread calls wait on the object on which *it holds lock* and then relies on some other thread to `notify` it

`notify` and `notifyAll` --> notifying will wake the thread/s up and put them into runnable queue and after the thread which called the notify on the lock releases the lock, one of the thread from the runnable queue will hold the lock.

`sleep` --> As the name suggests will stop the processing of the thread and put it at sleep for the amount of duration specified. Until someone interrupts or timeout occurs.

So the answer is *`notify`* will not cause thread to stop.

Answer (score 1):

`notify` will wake up the process or put it into run queue. Other two options you have given, puts the process in the wait queue.

Answer (score 0):

Wait and sleep will cause the thread to temporarily cease execution.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29

Notify will resume execution on a thread (or threads in the notifyAll case) that had wait called on before.

Given the three options, notify would be the most accurate answer